# Remove string from array if contains character

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How can I simply remove a string from an array, if it contact a character from `UITextField`?

For example: If `UITextField` contains the letters: "**Ap**", the array will only contains "**Ap**ple, **Ap**p, **Ap**so" but not "Al, Ben, Culo".

My Array:

```
let array = ["Audi", "BMW", "Lamborghini", "Toyota", "Mazda", "McLaren", "Volkswagen", "Ford", "Aston Martin", "Bentley"]
```

Code:

```
func setValue() {

        if let index = array.index(of: exerciseNameTextField.text!) {
            array.remove(at: index)
        }

´
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
let result = array.filter { $0.contains(exerciseNameTextField.text!) }
```

Comment: however, if this is a search functionality, it should be case insensitive and probably also diacritic insensitive. Therefore, `range(of:options:) != nil`  would be a better choice in this case.